# Installed Ubuntu on a separate ssd from Windows, Windows runs chkdsk at every startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, ssd

This might not be the right place to ask this but this has started right after I installed Ubuntu, hence it makes me wonder if the solution might have to do with Ubuntu as well.

Last weekend I set up a new SSD in my case and have successfully installed Ubuntu LTS on that SSD and have been using it happily for work since.

However, I have begun to notice that each time I boot back into Windows, it pulls up the 'Press any key to skip disk checking...' message before login pops up. I skipped it multiple times, then I followed online posts to turn off fast boot on Windows, sync Ubuntu and Windows clock and I edited the registry for Session Manager > BootExecute to add C: (Windows) drive as an exception to the auto disk check. No luck. I have also let the disk check run, and it reported no issues. Windows does not even mark any of the drives as 'dirty' hence I am at a complete loss as to why it still is insisting on prompting a check every time I boot into it.

I would appreciate any advice on how to deal with this situation. I am confident that my Windows drive is in good health and it was not doing this at all until I started Dual Booting.

Note: I run Windows 11. Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS Desktop.

Comment: My bad! I am using LTS Desktop, and I have not mounted the Windows disk on ubuntu aside from once, and since then I have unmounted it and the disk check continues to prompt running after. AFAIK it does not automatically mount when I boot into Ubuntu (I checked this as well). There aren't any other shared drives between the two OS. Windows does not even show the drive Ubuntu is installed on and I do not mount Windows while on Ubuntu.